# Does the "Urim and Thummim " decide who is a real priest just by a "yes" and "no" lot , in Ezra 2:63, or is it more complicated than this?

Tags: law, ezra, urim-and-tummim, priests

> *These searched for their family records, but they could not find them and so were excluded from the priesthood as unclean. The governor ordered them not to eat any of the most sacred food until there was a priest ministering with the Urim and Thummim.* (Ezra 2:62-63)

Of course, we acknowledge a supernatural ingredient in the process, even if it is just according to the proverb: *the giving of the lot is in the hand of the Lord.* But was there more to this than a "lot"?  A glowing? (Talisman were forbidden under the Law.) The Urim and Thummim were attached to the priest's breastplate, so were they taken off and used as a lot?

> *Also put the Urim and Thummim  in the breastplate so they may be over Aaron's heart whenever he enters the Presence of the Lord. Thus Aaron will always bear the means of making decisions for the Israelites over his heart before the LORD.* (Exodus 28:29-30)

This process for decision-making seemed to be quite reliable, and acceptable to the Israelites. Wherein did their confidence lay?

Answer (score 1):

In the OP's example the implication is that there was no priest who could minister with the Urim and Thummim, and the Jewish tradition holds that no priest in fact emerged who could do so (see @Ruminator's answer). So the question is hypothetical.

With that as a caveat, the hypothetical answer is "yes." The Urim and Thummin replied either yes or no. In those exceptional cases that went beyond this, follow-up questions might be asked to illicit further details. For example:

> David inquired of the Lord, who replied: Do not attack the
> front—circle behind them and come against them near the balsam trees.
> 24 When you hear the sound of marching in the tops of the balsam
> trees, act decisively, for then the Lord has already gone before you
> to strike the army of the Philistines. (2 Sam. 5)

This result could be achieved by a series of questions:

- Shall I attack? (yes)
- Shall I attack with a frontal assault? (no)
- Shall I circle around to attack near the balsam trees? (yes)
- Shall we then attack immediately? (no)
- Shall we wait for the noise of wind marching in the treetops to mask the sound of our attack? (yes)
- Will this be God's sign that he has gone before us to strike the Philistines? (yes)

Regarding the second question, Urim and Thummim were indeed attached to the priest's breastplate, and did not need to be removed when consulted, although the breastplate itself might be taken off. For example, when David wished to consult them, did not say "bring Urim and Thummin" but "bring the ephod." (1 Samuel 14:18, 1 Samuel 23:9, etc.)

**In the case cited in the Book of Ezra, no tactics were involved. It was a simple matter of whether the people in question were qualified to partake in certain sacred feasts or not. If a priest had ever come to administer Urim and Thummin, it would have been a binary yes-or-no question with no follow-ups needed.**

Comment: The process could also select individuals, apparently, by repeated divisions of a large mass; Achan, Joshua ch7 vv16-18. Saul, 1 Samuel ch10 vv2-21. In 1 Samuel ch14 v40, the first question was "Jonathan or one of the others?" which shortened the process.

Comment: @Dan Fefferman-Are there any Jewish writings in existence that explain the way the U and T worked. Any priestly records? Any historical references? "Yes and No" seem to be a very limited way of communicating.  The prophetic word was a lot more detailed from what we read  in the Scriptures. Although hard to interpret at times.

Comment: the most detailed description of the manner in which U/T should be consulted is probably [Yoma 73a 16-20](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.73a.18?lang=bi)

Comment: see [this article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4427467/jewish/What-Were-the-Urim-and-Thummim.htm) for other references.

Answer (score 0):

> ...In all cases except I Sam. x. 22 and II Sam. v. 23 et seq., the answer is either "Yes" or "No." It has been suggested by Riehm and others that these two passages have undergone editorial changes. After the death of David no instance is mentioned in the Old Testament of consulting the Lord by means of the Urim and Thummim or the ephod. This desuetude is undoubtedly occasioned by the growing influence of the Old Testament prophecy....

https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14609-urim-and-thummim#anchor3

Comment: @Ruminator-_After the death of David_ Was the time of Ezra _after_ the time of David? Or before? Even though  the governor asked for the U and T, did this mean they were still looking for it?

Comment: David was about 1000 BC/BCE, while Ezra was in the 500 BC/BCE, so about 500 years later. What Ezra was saying was that perhaps its use would return, and then they could use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no record of the Urim and Thummim being used for making decisions; however, there are several records of these sacred objects being placed on the High Priest's "**ephod**" or chest piece (either side of the 12 stones for Israel) on the same linin chest garment, Ex 28:30, Lev 8:8.

There are also several records stating that the Urim and Thummim would be designed to answer divine questions about God's will, Deut 33:8, 1 Sam 28:6, Num 27:21.

Despite all this we do have people making decisions using the "Ephod" which contained the Urim and Thummim:

- 1 Sam 23:9, 10 - When David learned that Saul was plotting evil against him, he said to Abiathar the priest, “**Bring the ephod**.” And David said, “O LORD, God of Israel, Your servant has heard that Saul intends to come to Keilah and destroy the city on my account.
- 1 Sam 30:7, 8 - Then David said to Abiathar the priest, the son of Ahimelech, “**Bring me the ephod**.” So Abiathar brought it to him, 8and David inquired of the LORD: “Should I pursue these raiders? Will I overtake them?” “Pursue them,” the LORD replied, “for you will surely overtake them and rescue the captives.”
- [1 Sam 14:8 is another highly debatable instance that might be the subject of another question.]

[Note that in these last few references, the Urim and Thummim are not mentioned - only the Ephod which had the Urim and Thummim on it.]

**Ezra 2:62-63**

> These searched for their family records, but they could not find them
> and so were excluded from the priesthood as unclean. The governor
> ordered them not to eat any of the most sacred food until there was a
> priest ministering with the Urim and Thummim.

The important point about this text is that the Urim and Thummim are tools used by the High Priest - and that is the point.  The Urim and Thummim were used by the High Priest BUT the Urim and Thummim were NOT used to choose the High Priest - that post was hereditary.

**Procedure for Urim and Thummim**

Just how (what procedure) the Urim and Thummim were used to make discissions is nowhere described.  We do not even know what the two objects were.

Comment: the procedure is described in the Talmud, but if "nowhere" refers to the OT, you final sentence is correct. BTW, the name U/T may not refer to two objecs but to a divine command to either do something or not. See the [Jewish Encyclopedia article](https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14609-urim-and-thummim) for a detailed consideration if this.

Comment: @DanFefferman - I agree - the U/T are not described in the OT.